# Upgrade from Xamarin Forms 4.8x to 5.0x throws Android Exception

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I upgraded an existing Xamarin Forms 4.8x to XF 5.0x and it is throwing an exception on loading the app in the emulator:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path:

I truncated after emulator: as the rest seemed quite specific to my app.

I am stuck - any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can see an exact error in Deploying to Device, You have to add the NuGet package that is displayed in error.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive the following error, it is because you are using AndroidX. To resolve this error, follow the instructions).

Remove the previous `<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">` tag

(AndroidX) Add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `<application>` tags:

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
          android:exported="false" 
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                     android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

Add a new folder called xml into your Resources folder and add a new XML file called `file_paths.xml`. Make sure that this `XML` file has a Build Action of: `AndroidResource`.

Add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```